# Date/Time not saved correctly?

Tags: 8, datetime

I made a date range field, and after entering some values and saving on first glance it looks ok, if i entered 20:00:00h it will display the same, but in the DB when i look at the stored values it's -2h (so 18:00:00). Anyone know why?

Also this is a huge problem when manually retrieving the values from the node, i fiddled around the time zones etc but i always get the value stored in the DB.

```
$node = Node::load($node_id);
$date = $node->get('field_date_ept2')->getValue()[0];
$result = \Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($date['value'], 'custom', 'Y-m-d\TH:i:s', 'Europe/Berlin);
echo $result; // 2019-12-12T18:00:00
```

p.s. the timezone in my drupal 8 site is "Europe/Berlin" and the same as in my `php.ini` file.

Answer (score 1):

The datetime value stored in DB is the UTC value. Any built in date formatter should give you the correct local time on the page. However if you need to manually get it from DB you'll have to convert the timezone yourself.

Comment: I updated my question with my code, sorry forgot to do that originally.

Comment: @lordZ3d Actually here's a much more detailed answer for you https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/229840/how-to-show-a-date-in-the-correct-timezone

Answer (score 0):

All dates are stored in UTC timezone. So your drupal account has a timezone set which is +2hours from UTC and drupal is converting that back to UTC before storing the date.

Here's how you can get the timezone back into the correct format in code. Elsewhere in views and stuff it should happen automatically:

```
$start_date = $v->field_MY_FIELD->start_date;
\Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($start_date->getTimestamp(), 'custom', 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

That will return it in whatever the current user/default site timezone is set as. Or you can specify the timezone:

```
\Drupal::service('date.formatter')->format($start_date->getTimestamp(), 'custom', 'Y-m-d H:i:s', 'Europe/London');
```

Comment: I did exactly that and I still get the wrong time, i will update my question with my code.

Comment: Can you do a dump of what your $date['value'] value actually is before you try it in the formatter?